# Looped code doesn't populate correct cells on certain sheets

Tags: vba, excel

The code below works correctly on certain sheets. The code is supposed to calculate the percent change from 1990 to 2012 and from 2005 to 2012, and put the calculations on the 4th and 5th row from the last non-empty row, respectively. All the sheets are identical except for  3. The sheets that are different only have a different number of years of data. For some reason this causes the VBA script to put the percent change calculations in random rows below the correct location. Also, the VBA script doesn't work correctly on one of the identical sheets. I have no idea why.

```
Sub PercentChangeCalPIP()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim sheet_name As Range
For Each sheet_name In Sheets("WS").Range("I:I")
    If sheet_name.Value = "" Then
        Exit For
    Else
    With Sheets(sheet_name.Value)
'90-20## Percent Change
iRow = 14
Cell_val = .Cells(iRow, 1)
While Cell_val <> ""
    iRow = iRow + 3
    Cell_val = .Cells(iRow, 1)
Wend
.Cells(iRow + 3, 1) = "1990-2012"
'Column B,2

Cell_val = .Cells(iRow, 2)
While Cell_val <> ""
    iRow = iRow + 3
    Cell_val = .Cells(iRow, 2)
Wend
.Cells(iRow + 3, 2) = "=((B14/VLOOKUP(1990, A14:B46, 2,FALSE))-1)"
'Column C,3

Cell_val = .Cells(iRow, 3)
While Cell_val <> ""
    iRow = iRow + 3
    Cell_val = .Cells(iRow, 3)
Wend
.Cells(iRow + 3, 3) = "=((C14/VLOOKUP(1990, A14:C46, 3,FALSE))-1)"
'Column D,4

Cell_val = .Cells(iRow, 4)
While Cell_val <> ""
    iRow = iRow + 3
    Cell_val = .Cells(iRow, 4)
Wend
.Cells(iRow + 3, 4) = "=((D14/VLOOKUP(1990, A14:D46, 4,FALSE))-1)"
'Column E,5

Cell_val = .Cells(iRow, 5)
While Cell_val <> ""
    iRow = iRow + 3
    Cell_val = .Cells(iRow, 5)
Wend
.Cells(iRow + 3, 5) = "=((E14/VLOOKUP(1990, A14:E46, 5,FALSE))-1)"
'05-20## Percent Changes
Cell_val = .Cells(iRow, 1)
While Cell_val <> ""
    iRow = iRow + 4
    Cell_val = .Cells(iRow, 1)
Wend
.Cells(iRow + 4, 1) = "2005-2012"
'Column B,2

Cell_val = .Cells(iRow, 2)
While Cell_val <> ""
    iRow = iRow + 4
    Cell_val = .Cells(iRow, 2)
Wend
.Cells(iRow + 4, 2) = "=((B14/VLOOKUP(2005, A14:B46, 2,FALSE))-1)"
'Column C,3

Cell_val = .Cells(iRow, 3)
While Cell_val <> ""
    iRow = iRow + 4
    Cell_val = .Cells(iRow, 3)
Wend
.Cells(iRow + 4, 3) = "=((C14/VLOOKUP(2005, A14:C46, 3,FALSE))-1)"
'Column D,4

Cell_val = .Cells(iRow, 4)
While Cell_val <> ""
    iRow = iRow + 4
    Cell_val = .Cells(iRow, 4)
Wend
.Cells(iRow + 4, 4) = "=((D14/VLOOKUP(2005, A14:D46, 4,FALSE))-1)"
'Column E,5

Cell_val = .Cells(iRow, 5)
While Cell_val <> ""
    iRow = iRow + 4
    Cell_val = .Cells(iRow, 5)
Wend
.Cells(iRow + 4, 5) = "=((E14/VLOOKUP(2005, A14:E46, 5,FALSE))-1)"
End With
        End If
    Next sheet_name
End Sub
```

Any thoughts as to what might be the problem?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the sheet is diferent??? maybe the lookup fails?? did you try debug it and see where it fails???

Comment: The code doesn't fail exactly. It just doesn't place the calculations in the correct spots on certain sheets.

Comment: Did you try copying the sheet data to another and give it another try? maybe the sheet has hidden columns or something..

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work unfortunately. I did however fix the problem by changing `iRow = 14` to `iRow = .Cells(14, 1).End(xlDown).Row` and got rid of all the while loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 While Cell_val <> ""
 iRow = iRow + 3
```

Instead of jumping rows by increment of 3, why not to try with 1 if there are consecutive non-empty cells in the column.

```
 iRow = iRow + 1
```

Maybe you have your own intention here that I am missing out. But using interval jumps to select right row seems to be a little bit odd to me.

Comment: I wish I could post some pictures of the worksheets to give a better idea. Essentially, I need the percent calculations to populate `iRow = iRow + 3` and `iRow = iRow + 4` for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: The number of rows that are non-empty are exactly the multiplication of 3 or 4?

Comment: There are exactly 3 empty rows between the last row of data and the first row of percent changes. I did fix the problem by changing `iRow = 14` to `iRow = .Cells(14, 1).End(xlDown).Row` and got rid of all the while loops. However, the code is still giving me trouble on one of the sheets. For some reason on that one sheet it creates duplicate percent change calculations and puts them where I have technical notes describing the data (these notes start two lines below where the percent change calculations are).

Comment: I noticed that you were using one variable iRow repeatedly as a moving index. Maybe you can debug your code by tracking iRow. Sometime, just insert Msgbox(iRow) between the lines to read iRow. This could help you to understand where and when exactly the result is inserted.